# Incorrect timezone display with Moment.js when non-whole hour offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using Moment Version 2.0.0 and for some reason i don't want to update version to 2.0.1 or above.

When i am using following code block; it shows me the correct timezone offset that is +5:30

```
moment().format("Z");
```

But when i am trying with below code its NOT showing me +0530 instead it showed me +0550

```
moment().format("ZZ");
```

So, am i missing something here.
I got the solution by using below code; But i don't recommend to use regular expression. Is there any Moment solution for this.

```
new Date().toTimeString().match(/([-\+][0-9]+)\s/)[1]
```

Thanks

Comment: So Z gives you +0530 and ZZ gives you +0550. What do you get from javascript built-in getTimezoneOffset()?   Like, run this: var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

Comment: As given in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: Hmmm... I just tested moment using the same things you did and I get consistent results. Z gives me -05:00 and ZZ gives me -0500 If you run them at the same time, what do you get right now? console.log both of then in the same script.

Comment: Did it but not working; result => Z: +05:30 ZZ: +0550
What Moment version are you using? It must be 2.0.0 and NOT above.
and Can you try it with +5:30 timezone offset !

Comment: I see. I was using 2.4. I suppose using older versions this is just the price you pay... they have more bugs.

Comment: I updated my momentjs with 2.4. But it still not working. As the format tokens z and zz is deprecated in the 1.6.0 Moment release.
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162

In Moment version 2.1.0 release the ability to set offset with moment#zone. So i guess there must be some good possible way.

I have raised the issue https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1270

Comment: I also found that for some timezone offset it working as expected but not for all.

I updated my momentjs with 2.4. But it still not working. As the format tokens z and zz is deprecated in the 1.6.0 Moment release.
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162

In Moment version 2.1.0 release the ability to set offset with moment#zone. So i guess there must be some good possible way.

I have raised the issue https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1270

Comment: Also added http://jsfiddle.net/6VtSM/ Check it out here. Note: Before running this fiddle; Change your Time Zone to (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

Comment: Also i have added ```http://jsfiddle.net/hegdeashwin/Jf3Nx/2/``` Check it out here. Note: Before running this fiddle; Change your Time Zone to (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved my Moment JS Development team; They have provided me with response to get the pull request.

Issues Raised:
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1270

Issues Solved:
https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/1278

File Changed:
https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/1278/files

Thanks for your Help.